# How to use Google Cloud Speech API directly on client side

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I want to post my audio stream directly to Google Cloud Speech API by XHR.

After going through the documentation at: https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1#streamingrecognizerequest, however I am a little bit confused.

1. What url should I post to? I can find URL for both Async and Sync recognize, but I don't know what URL should I post to for streaming Recognize?
2. I want to send audio stream directly to API from client. How can I convert stream data to acceptable type for API? Which encoding method should I use?